# ActiveAdmin - Devise error after login (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I use devise for login in ActiveAdmin (backend) and FrontEnd (registered user and login) and I have two models for each one (`AdminUser` and `User` respectively).

Also, I use `role_model` and `CanCan` for restrict actions for AdminUsers. I have 5 roles: `superadmin, administrator, cashier, operator, accountant` and my app only works fine when the AdminUser is superadmin or cashier. If that user have another role, when login, I got the error: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Model **admin_user.rb**:

```
require 'role_model'

class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:

  include RoleModel


  roles_attribute :roles_mask

  roles :superadmin, :administrator, :cashier, :operator, :accountant

  # Relations with Tables

  def to_s
    self.email
  end

end
```

Initializer **active_admin.rb**:

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  config.site_title = "App-1"  
  config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter
  config.authentication_method = :authenticate_active_admin_user!
  config.current_user_method   = :current_user
  config.logout_link_path      = :destroy_user_session_path
  config.logout_link_method    = :delete
  config.skip_before_filter :authenticate_admin_user!
  # config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
  # config.authorization_adapter = ActiveAdmin::CanCanAdapter
  config.cancan_ability_class = "Ability"
  # config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user
  config.batch_actions = true
  config.localize_format = :long
end
```

**routes.rb**:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  devise_for :users
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  # Other URLS

end
```

Do I have some error in my configuration or routes?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: You are overwriting some config items in your `ActiveAdmin.setup` block. For example `config.authentication_method`.

Comment: @Uzbekjon If I remove some duplicate config items. I get: `undefined method 'superadmin?' for nil:NilClass`